# HTML form input direct to URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

How do I direct the browser to another URL based on user input for example:

abc.com/apple.html

abc.com/banana.html

abc.com/pear.html

BUT, if the user doesn't enter apple,banana or pear then they are directed to:

abc.com/wrong.html

Any help would be awesome! I only know HTML forms.

Comment: you have to use some server side or client side language to process it..

Comment: I'm in banking. I have no idea how to do this. Can you write me a simple form I can cut and paste into my html page????

Comment: without any more information we cannot help you.

Comment: Skatox, what other info do you need?

Comment: just the backend's (server side) language

Comment: It's a HTML page hosted by GoDaddy. I'd imagine you could use any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
                <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
            </form>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
            function redirect() {
                var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
                switch(input) {
                    case 'apple':
                        window.location.replace('apple.html');
                        break;
                    case 'banana':
                        window.location.replace('banana.html');
                        break;
                    default:
                        window.location.replace('default.html');
                        break;
                }


            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Joe, I have an image as the submit but, how do I incorporate that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Javascript/JQuery` to do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form_input" action="post_values.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS/JQuery:**

```
<script>
   $("form").submit(function() {
     var fruit = $("#fruit").val();
     if(fruit=='apple' || fruit=='pear' || fruit=='banana'){
        window.location = "http://www.abc.com/"+fruit+".html";
     }else{
        window.location = "http://www.abc.com/wrong.html";
     }
     return true;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I cut and pasteed into a html page and it didn't work? I substituted abc with my site and everything. Does it work for you Alphamale?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML file of "abc.com", which is mostly `index.html`, between your `<HEAD>` tags do this:

```
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.abc.com/wrong.html">
```

Adjust `content=` to how many seconds you want your browser to wait before redirecting.

**Update:**

The http method is not recommended by W3C because of this:

`If a page redirects too quickly (less than 2-3 seconds), using the "Back" button on the next page may cause some browsers to move back to the redirecting page, whereupon the redirect will occur again. This is bad for usability, as this may cause a reader to be "stuck" on the last website.`

Hence the recommended method via JS:

```
    <head>
    <script>
        function replaceDoc()
        {
        window.location.replace("http://www.abc.com/wrong.html")
        }
    </script>
    </head>
```

I found the above method here:

[W3Schools Window.Replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var page = new Array("apple","banana","pear");   // list of your pages
    function redirect(){
        if(page.indexOf(document.forms["NameOfForm"]["NameOfInput"].value)!=-1){
            window.location = document.forms["NameOfForm"]["NameOfInput"].value + ".html";
        }
        else {
            window.location = "wrong.html";
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form name="NameOfForm" onsubmit="return redirect()">
    <input name="NameOfInput" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

put that code into `abc.com/` and you just have to add, change the list of page ;)